# How to reduce the number of pages in pagination

Tags: pagination

The code below is the function for pagination in my wordpress blog. Presently it outputs 7 pages and then the .. last page number.

How can I reduce this number so it shows only 5 pages and then ... last page number?

```
function emm_paginate_loop($start, $max, $page = 0) {
    $output = "";
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        $output .= ($page === intval($i)) 
            ? "<span class='emm-page emm-current'>$i</span>" 
            : "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($i) . "' class='emm-page'>$i</a>";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Hi netfreak.. I just checked the codes and yes gap is the default 3. As per the comments,  

'range' - Default is 3 (int). The number of page links to show before and after the current page.

'gap' - Default is 3 (int). The minimum number of pages before a gap is replaced with ellipses (...)

But it still is quite confusing. Right now the pagination is shown as 'Previous' 1 2 3 4 5 6 7...30 'Next'

I'd like to reduce it to 'Previous' 1 2 3 ..30 'Next'

Any ideas??

Comment: Fixed it.. changed the default to 2 and it now shows just 5 as I wanted it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're using 2 custom functions one of them is emm_paginate_loop() you're showing. But i saw that settings for that custom pagination is on function emm_paginate() and specifically "gap":

> 'gap' - Default is 3 (int). The minimum number of pages before a gap is 
>         replaced with ellipses (...).

But that only sets a minimum number...

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using a plugin for this. [WP-Paginate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/) gives you this option along with other options that might be useful

**Edit**
Since a plugin isn't advisable for a mobile site, maybe you could add `$range = 5` to the function

```
function emm_paginate_loop($start, $max, $page = 0, $range = 5) {
    $output = "";
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        $output .= ($page === intval($i)) 
            ? "<span class='emm-page emm-current'>$i</span>" 
            : "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($i) . "' class='emm-page'>$i</a>";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Chip.. this is for a mobile theme.. so less plugins the better.

Comment: I didn't catch that from the original post, my apologies.

Comment: No worries mate.. Cheers and thanks for 'Chip'ing in!!